# What is the comparisons of what an active key and an owner key can do?

Tags: active-key, owner-key

From my understanding an owner key lets you do everything. But what is everything? Sending? Staking? Changing the owner keys?

And an Active key is everything **Except** for changing the owner keys?

What is the list of the functions what each can do and its purpose?